# Using Cheetah Templating Engine with Tornado Web Framework

Tags: python, caching, tornado, cheetah

Has anyone used the Cheetah Templating Engine with the Tornado Web Framework before? Do they work well together and are you able to use Cheetah's caching components within the Tornado Framework?

I've been looking for a good, python only solution for this. I originally looking at Twisted for the Web Framework but it is not able to make use of the caching aspects of the Cheetah engine making any benefits from it limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Cheetah and Tornado both, but never together.  Cheetah's caching is not all that super (as far as time saving).  From what I remember, and this may be wrong, but it's caching is just a way of preventing the lookup in the lookup table from taking place.  But you still have to actually provide the lookup table to allow for expired cache items to be updated.

Also, why wouldn't Twisted be able to take the same advantage of the Cheetah template caching?

Take a look at this link:
http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-web/2004-July/000552.html

It is a bit dated, but may be helpful.

Comment: The way it was explained to me, twisted was not able to to take advantage of the Cheetah Caching due to the nature of how the web.py implementation works. I'll admit that I do not have any first hand experience with Twisted and have just been researching the components I should use for building a web application I'm designing. Is the information I was given not an accurate assessment?

Comment: I am not sure what part of the web.py implementation would prevent it from working as I have never attempted to use Cheetah with Twisted.  However, I did find this dated link which may serve as a good test case to start from: http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-web/2004-July/000552.html

Comment: Excellent link. I'll have to look it over. Could you toss that information into the Answer section? I'd like to give credit where credit is due.